# Is it possible to set Tomcat's threadpool size programmatically in Tomcat 9?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I see lots of information about how to do it via xml configuration, but I'm using embedded Tomcat and would like to set it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize Tomcat almost the same way programmatically and with XML.

For instance, the `maxThreads` property in XML that is used to limit the thread-pool size can be also set up the following way :

```java
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
Connector connector = tomcat.getConnector();
connector.setProperty("maxThreads", "2");
```

This should work on any XML property.